# Using Axios GET with Authorization Header in React-Native App

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, http-headers, fetch, axios

I'm trying to use axios for a GET request with an API which requires an `Authorization` header.

My current code:

```js
const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + USER_TOKEN;
```

where `USER_TOKEN` is the access token needed. This string concatenation may be the issue as if I post this as `AuthStr = 'Bearer 41839y750138-391'`, the following GET request works and returns the data I'm after.

```js
axios.get(URL, { 'headers': { 'Authorization': AuthStr } })
  .then((response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I also tried setting this as a global header with no success.

Comment: what does console.log('Bearer ' + USER_TOKEN) give?

Comment: It gives Bearer 472397403110 (or whatever token number)

Comment: what does console.log(typeof(USER_TOKEN)) give?

Comment: Try using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat). It is the recommended javascript way of string concatination

Comment: No change using concat. And typeof gives string return

Comment: working: axios.get(URL, { 'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Bearer 57290850420852' }  }).then ...../n Not Working: any other version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132552/discussion-between-swapnil-and-ally-haire).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For anyone else that comes across this post and might find it useful...
There is actually nothing wrong with my code. I made the mistake of requesting client_credentials type access code instead of password access code (#facepalms).
FYI I am using urlencoded post hence the use of querystring..
So for those that may be looking for some example code.. here is my full request

Big thanks to @swapnil for trying to help me debug this.

```js
   const data = {
      grant_type: USER_GRANT_TYPE,
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      scope: SCOPE_INT,
      username: DEMO_EMAIL,
      password: DEMO_PASSWORD
    };



  axios.post(TOKEN_URL, Querystring.stringify(data))   
   .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      USER_TOKEN = response.data.access_token;
      console.log('userresponse ' + response.data.access_token); 
    })   
   .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error ' + error);   
   });



const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(USER_TOKEN); 
axios.get(URL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } })
 .then(response => {
     // If request is good...
     console.log(response.data);
  })
 .catch((error) => {
     console.log('error ' + error);
  });
```

Comment: how to pass multiple custom header in axios

Comment: `axios.get(uri, { headers: { "custom-header-1": "value", "custom-header-2": "value" } })`

Comment: Do you have a header example to do it with Amplify and Apigateway? :) just asking

Comment: Thank you! Made it 50.

Answer (score 6):

Could not get this to work until I put Authorization in single quotes:

axios.get(URL, { headers: { 'Authorization': AuthStr } })

Comment: This shouldn't matter