# how to set headers iniside axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

I have two headers, the first one contains APP_TOKEN and the second contains APP_TOKEN and USER_TOKEN, how do I condition if my request requires only APP_TOKEN or APP_TOKEN and USER_TOKEN on axios

this is my axios

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create((param_app){
  if(param_app == APP_TOKEN){
    baseURL: 'http://exampe',
    headers: {
      'timeout' : 30000,
      'APP_TOKEN': 'apptoken_example',
    }
  }else if(param_app === APP_TOKEN && USER_TOKEN){
    baseURL: 'http://exampe',
    headers: {
      'timeout' : 30000,
      'APP_TOKEN': 'apptoken_example',
      'USER_TOKEN': JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')).TOKEN
    }
  }
})
```

for example this login page only requires APP_TOKEN for headers

```
async handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    if(this.state.MEMBER_EMAIL && this.state.MEMBER_PASSWORD){
      const headers = {
        'timeout' : 30000,
        'APP_TOKEN': 'example',
      }
      await API.post('member/login', this.state ,{headers})
      .then((response) => {
        let responseJson = response
        if(responseJson.data.STATUS_CODE === '200'){
          this.props.resSave('data', JSON.stringify(responseJson.data.DATA))
          this.setState({
            redirect: true
          })
        }else if(responseJson.data.STATUS_CODE === '400') {
          alert(responseJson.data.MESSAGE)
          this.setState({
            redirect: false
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

and this is an example of a page that requires APP_TOKEN and USER_TOKEN

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const headers = {
      'timeout' : 30000,
      'APP_TOKEN': 'example',
      'USER_TOKEN': JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')).TOKEN
    }
    await API.get("/banner-home", {headers})
    .then(response=>this.setState({
      banner:response.data.DATA,
      loading:false
    }))
  }
```

Comment: You need to switch around the conditions in the first code block. You first want to check that both values are there and if that is not the case check if only the APP_TOKEN is there. Currently, if APP_TOKEN token is present if will never reach the second test.

Comment: how to mark it?

Comment: @Martijn  can you post your comment as an answer so that Muhamad can mark it as an answer?

Comment: can, if the problem is solved

Comment: What did you mean by "how to mark" ? I thought it was answer to your question, and you wanted to mark as accepted.

Comment: so sorry I confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Axios GET with Authorization Header in React-Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519092/using-axios-get-with-authorization-header-in-react-native-app)

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch around the conditions in the first code block. You first want to check that both values are there and if that is not the case check if only the APP_TOKEN is there. Currently, if APP_TOKEN token is present if will never reach the second test.